# clang target option for riscv64 doesn't work

Tags: clang, llvm, riscv

I'm trying to use clang to make IR for riscv64.

When I use llc --version, it shows many targets including riscv64.

But when I use the following command:

```
clang -target riscv64 hello.c
clang -target riscv64-unknown-linux hello.c
```

It shows **clang-4.0: error: unknown target triple 'riscv64-unknown-linux', please use -triple or -arch**

I'm not using ucb-bar's llvm for riscv. I'm using riscv from upstream of llvm.org.

Did I do something wrong or do I have to do something before building llvm?

Answer (score -1):

Try `elf` instead of `linux`.

```
clang -target riscv32-unknown-elf
clang -target riscv64-unknown-elf
```

Edit: I created [this repo](https://github.com/Lichtso/riscv-llvm-templates) for everyone interested in using RISC-V with LLVM.